# Combining Forms, JSON, AJAX, PHP and google graphs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm very new to JScript, Ajax and Google Graphs. But I'm trying to combine everything, I've coded them all separately and got them working but having a lot of issues bringing it all together.

**Google Graph Part of my code(Form does nothing here):**

```
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Dashboard Application</title><meta name=keywords content=Dashboard Application, some of my best frieds are search engines/><script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script><link type="text/css" href="jquery.simple-dtpicker.css" rel="stylesheet" /><script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.simple-dtpicker.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"><script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
                <link type="text/css" href="jquery.simple-dtpicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
                <!---->

                <style type="text/css">
                        body { background-color: #ffffff; padding-left: 1%; padding-bottom: 100px; }
                        footer{font-size:small;position:fixed;right:5px;bottom:5px;}
                </style>
                <style>h1 {color:white; font-size:24pt; text-align:center;font-family:arial,sans-serif }.menu {color:white; font-size:12pt; text-align:center;font-family:arial,sans-serif; font-weight:bold }table2 {background:black }p {color:black; font-size:12pt; text-align:justify;font-family:arial,sans-serif }p.foot {color:white; font-size:9pt; text-align:center;font-family:arial,sans-serif; font-weight:bold }a:link, a:visited, a:active {color:white} </style></head>
        <body>
        <table width=100% cellpadding=12 cellspacing=0 border=0><tr bgcolor=black><td align=left><img src="logo.png" width=150 height=150/></td><td><h1>Engineering Dashboard</h1></td><td align=right><img src=logo.png width=150 height=150/> </td></tr> </table><table class='table2' width=100% border=0 bgcolor=black cellpadding=4 cellspacing=0> 
        <tr>
        <td width=50%><a href=googletestform.php><img src=as-logo.png width=20 height=20 alt=Google Graphs+Form border=0 /></a><a href=googletestform.php><span class=menu>Google Graphs+Form</span></a></td><td width=50%><a href=logout.php><img src=as-logo.png width=20 height=20 alt=Log Out border=0 /></a><a href=logout.php><span class=menu>Log Out</span></a></td></tr>
        </table>
        <form id="graphinput" method=POST>
                <table width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="0"><tr>
                <td width="10%">Start Date:</td>
                <td width="20%">
                <input type="text" name="startDateTime" value="">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(function(){
                                $('*[name=startDateTime]').appendDtpicker();
                        });
                </script></td>

                <td width="10%">End Date:</td>
                <td width="20%">
                <input type="text" name="endDateTime" value="">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(function(){
                                $('*[name=endDateTime]').appendDtpicker();
                        });
                </script></td><td width="30%" ><select name="table"><option value="PHY_Short_CHA_ESW">PHY_Short_CHA_ESW</option><option value="PHY_Short_Cache_Usage_Rate">PHY_Short_Cache_Usage_Rate</option><option value="PHY_Short_DKA_ESW">PHY_Short_DKA_ESW</option><option value="PHY_Short_ESW_Cache">PHY_Short_ESW_Cache</option><option value="PHY_Short_MP">PHY_Short_MP</option><option value="PHY_Short_MPPCB_ESW">PHY_Short_MPPCB_ESW</option><option value="PHY_Short_PG">PHY_Short_PG</option><option value="PHY_Short_Write_Pending_Rate">PHY_Short_Write_Pending_Rate</option><option value="Port_IOPS">Port_IOPS</option><option value="Port_Initiator_IOPS">Port_Initiator_IOPS</option><option value="Port_Initiator_KBPS">Port_Initiator_KBPS</option><option value="Port_Initiator_Response">Port_Initiator_Response</option><option value="Port_KBPS">Port_KBPS</option><option value="Port_Response">Port_Response</option></select></td><td width="10%" ><select name="graph"><option value="ALL">ALL</option><option value="AVG&MAX">AVG&MAX</option></select></td></tr></table><table><tr><td width=100%><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr></table></form><div id="response"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">


            // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
            google.load("visualization", "1", {"packages":["corechart"]});

            // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            function drawChart() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "get_sql_data.php",
                //type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (phpdata) {
                    // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
                    var chartdata = new google.visualization.DataTable(phpdata);

                    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
                    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("chart_div"));
                    chart.draw(chartdata, {width: 1600, height: 500});
                }
            });
            }

            </script>

            <!--this is the div that will hold the pie chart-->
            <div id="chart_div"></div><table width=100% bgcolor=black cellpaddin g=0 border=0><tr><td><p class=foot>&copy; root Dashboard</p><p class=foot>Please see our <a href=legal.php>Legal Information Page</a></p></td></tr></table></body>
        </html>
```

**The Text only version(Want to take the data from the form returned in a string here and graph it):**

```
            <html>
            <head>
            <title>Dashboard Application</title><meta name=keywords content=Dashboard Application, some of my best frieds are search engines/><script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script><link type="text/css" href="jquery.simple-dtpicker.css" rel="stylesheet" /><script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.simple-dtpicker.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"><script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
                    <link type="text/css" href="jquery.simple-dtpicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
                    <!---->

                    <style type="text/css">
                            body { background-color: #ffffff; padding-left: 1%; padding-bottom: 100px; }
                            footer{font-size:small;position:fixed;right:5px;bottom:5px;}
                    </style>
                    <style>h1 {color:white; font-size:24pt; text-align:center;font-family:arial,sans-serif }.menu {color:white; font-size:12pt; text-align:center;font-family:arial,sans-serif; font-weight:bold }table2 {background:black }p {color:black; font-size:12pt; text-align:justify;font-family:arial,sans-serif }p.foot {color:white; font-size:9pt; text-align:center;font-family:arial,sans-serif; font-weight:bold }a:link, a:visited, a:active {color:white} </style></head>
            <body>
            <table width=100% cellpadding=12 cellspacing=0 border=0><tr bgcolor=black><td align=left><img src="logo.png" width=150 height=150/></td><td><h1>Engineering Dashboard</h1></td><td align=right><img src=logo.png width=150 height=150/> </td></tr> </table><table class='table2' width=100% border=0 bgcolor=black cellpadding=4 cellspacing=0> 
            <tr>
            <td width=50%><a href=googletestform.php><img src=as-logo.png width=20 height=20 alt=Google Graphs+Form border=0 /></a><a href=googletestform.php><span class=menu>Google Graphs+Form</span></a></td><td width=50%><a href=logout.php><img src=as-logo.png width=20 height=20 alt=Log Out border=0 /></a><a href=logout.php><span class=menu>Log Out</span></a></td></tr>
            </table>
            <form id="graphinput" method=POST>
                    <table width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="0"><tr>
                    <td width="10%">Start Date:</td>
                    <td width="20%">
                    <input type="text" name="startDateTime" value="">
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(function(){
                                    $('*[name=startDateTime]').appendDtpicker();
                            });
                    </script></td>

                    <td width="10%">End Date:</td>
                    <td width="20%">
                    <input type="text" name="endDateTime" value="">
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(function(){
                                    $('*[name=endDateTime]').appendDtpicker();
                            });
                    </script></td><td width="30%" ><select name="table"><option value="PHY_Short_CHA_ESW">PHY_Short_CHA_ESW</option><option value="PHY_Short_Cache_Usage_Rate">PHY_Short_Cache_Usage_Rate</option><option value="PHY_Short_DKA_ESW">PHY_Short_DKA_ESW</option><option value="PHY_Short_ESW_Cache">PHY_Short_ESW_Cache</option><option value="PHY_Short_MP">PHY_Short_MP</option><option value="PHY_Short_MPPCB_ESW">PHY_Short_MPPCB_ESW</option><option value="PHY_Short_PG">PHY_Short_PG</option><option value="PHY_Short_Write_Pending_Rate">PHY_Short_Write_Pending_Rate</option><option value="Port_IOPS">Port_IOPS</option><option value="Port_Initiator_IOPS">Port_Initiator_IOPS</option><option value="Port_Initiator_KBPS">Port_Initiator_KBPS</option><option value="Port_Initiator_Response">Port_Initiator_Response</option><option value="Port_KBPS">Port_KBPS</option><option value="Port_Response">Port_Response</option></select></td><td width="10%" ><select name="graph"><option value="ALL">ALL</option><option value="AVG&MAX">AVG&MAX</option></select></td></tr></table><table><tr><td width=100%><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr></table></form><div id="response"></div><div id="response"></div>


            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#graphinput").submit(function(){

                    // show that something is loading
                    $("#response").html("<b>Loading response...</b>");

                    /*
                     * "post_receiver.php" - where you will pass the form data
                     * $(this).serialize() - to easily read form data
                     * function(data){... - data contains the response from post_receiver.php
                     */
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "get_sql_data.php", 
                        data: $(this).serialize()
                    })
                    .done(function(data){

                        // show the response
                        $("#response").html(data);

                    })
                    .fail(function() {

                        // just in case posting your form failed
                        alert( "Posting failed." );

                    });

                    // to prevent refreshing the whole page page
                    return false;

                });
            });
            </script>
            <table width=100% bgcolor=black cellpaddin g=0 border=0><tr><td><p class=foot>&copy; root Dashboard</p><p class=foot>Please see our <a href=legal.php>Legal Information Page</a></p></td></tr></table></body>
            </html>
```

When I try and combine the two as soon as I press the submit button it just opens a new page and keeps saying connecting to www.google.com. Any ideas on how I can graph the txt data?

**Here is my attempt that doesn't work:**
                
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#graphinput").submit(function(){

```
                    // show that something is loading
                    $("#response").html("<b>Loading response...</b>");

                    /*
                     * "post_receiver.php" - where you will pass the form data
                     * $(this).serialize() - to easily read form data
                     * function(data){... - data contains the response from post_receiver.php
                     */
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "get_sql_data.php", 
                        data: $(this).serialize()
                    })
                    .done(function(data){

                        // show the response
                        // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
                        google.load("visualization", "1", {"packages":["corechart"]});

                        // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
                        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

                        function drawChart() {

                                // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
                                var chartdata = new google.visualization.DataTable(data);

                                // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
                                var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("response"));
                                chart.draw(chartdata, {width: 1600, height: 500});

                        }





                    })
                    .fail(function() {

                        // just in case posting your form failed
                        alert( "Posting failed." );

                    });

                    // to prevent refreshing the whole page page
                    return false;

                });
            });
            </script>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

Saw my error, I was trying to graph using the wrong data type:
My Current working code:

```
<script>
                //Load core chart visualization package
                google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"]});

                //On load call back initiate function
                google.setOnLoadCallback(getData);


                function getData() {

                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#graphinput").submit(function(){

                        // show that something is loading
                        $("#response").html("<b>Loading response...</b>");

                        /*
                         * "post_receiver.php" - where you will pass the form data
                         * $(this).serialize() - to easily read form data
                         * function(data){... - data contains the response from post_receiver.php
                         */
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "get_sql_data.php",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: $(this).serialize()

                        })
                        .done(function(data){

                            // show the response
                            //$("#response").html(data);
                            var chartdata = new google.visualization.DataTable(data);

                            // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
                            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("response"));
                            chart.draw(chartdata, {width: 1600, height: 500});

                        })
                        .fail(function() {

                            // just in case posting your form failed
                            alert( "Posting failed." );

                        });

                        // to prevent refreshing the whole page page
                        return false;

                    });
                });
                }

            </script>
```